# HTML Click Works in IE, not FireFox, Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox-3

This has got to be something simple:  I set up a frames page with two possible sources for the target frame based on a form with two options.  I used the OnClick event to trap the user's click to show the appropriate page.  It works fine in Internet Explorer 7, swapping the two source pages.  FireFox 3 and Chrome show only the default source.

HEAD Script section:

```
function SwapInlineFrameSource()

{
var rsRadio, rsiFrame;

rsRadio=document.getElementById('County');

rsiFrame=document.getElementById('RatesFrame')

if (rsRadio.checked===true) {

    rsiFrame.src="SantaCruzRates.htm";

    }

else {

    rsiFrame.src="DelNorteRates.htm";

    }

}
```

BODY Form section (commented to show up here):

```
<input type="radio" value="SC" checked name="County"   onclick="SwapInlineFrameSource()"> 
    Santa Cruz
<input type="radio" value="DN" name="County" onclick="SwapInlineFrameSource()" > 
    Del Norte
```

What am I missing?  (Live example: http://www.raintrees.com/rates.html)

Thanks!

mr

Comment: What's === do? Really really equal?

Comment: Good question. that might be the reason. Try: if (rsRadio.checked) { ...

Comment: It prevents type coercion  "1" == 1 will be true "1" === 1 will be false due to different types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using getElementByID, but you aren't specifying IDs for your inputs. Perhaps consider this instead:

```
function SwapInlineFrameSource(rdoButton)
{
  rsiFrame = document.getElementById("RatesFrame");
  rsiFrame.src = rdoButton.value;
}

<input type="radio" value="SantaCruzRates.htm" checked="checked" name="County" onClick="SwapInlineFrameSource(this);">Santa Cruz</input>
<input type="radio" value="DelNorteRates.htm" name="County" onClick="SwapInlineFrameSource(this);">Del Norte</input>
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this: in IE, the getElementByID function actually searches both name and id attributes, which causes this code to work (accidentally) in IE. If there's more than one element with the specified name, I believe it returns the first one it finds.

Comment: You both helped!  The code above is much cleaner and simpler than mine (a definite win in my book) and Will's elaboration explained why it was working in IE and not other browsers.  I added the missing ID attribute to my Frame and presto, it worked.

Thanks!

mr

Comment: Thanks for that Will. I don't know why I didn't include that information in my answer. Your clarificatio is greatly appreciated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong....

```
var rsRadio, rsiFrame;
rsRadio=document.getElementById('County');
rsiFrame=document.getElementById('RatesFrame')
if (rsRadio.checked===true) {
```

I assume you mean getElementsByName and not ID becasue you don't have an ID of county on those radio buttons.

In fact you need to determine which radio button is checked so you could some thing like (assuming there are only ever the 2 options)

```
if(document.getElementsByName()[0].checked){
    // show Santa Cruz Rates
}else{
    // show other rates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that getElementById works on frames in firefox. I have always used the frames["frameID"], which seems to work more consistently.

Comment: getElementById works fine on iframes, but it returns the iframe element node, not the ‘window’ object for that frame as returned by window.frames[]. This behaviour is the same for Firefox and IE. ‘src’ should be set on the iframe element node as it is an HTML attribute.